# Flutter multiline textfield how to make text bold in middle

Tags: dart, flutter

When the user want to post an atricle they write so for that i  created a textfield to do that . when user wants bold the text form the pointer where the button is pressed.he should bold text from there if user again press the button it should get the normal text from there.. i didnt find any way to that does any one suggest a way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/zefyr is a package that allows you to do that.

Otherwise you can follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12675

Comment: Is there anything better than this

Comment: Better how? I don't think so though.

Comment: Am sorry this only package which supports these functions or any other official fluter package to do that that it!!

Comment: Can we change the fontsize over this zefyr

Comment: Don't know I haven't used it myself yet. I'd expect so though. You could create an issue in the package GitHub repo to get a response from the maintainer.